# Proof of $\ln{ab} = \ln{a} + \ln{b}$ using the limit definition of $\ln{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I have seen proofs for $\ln{ab} = \ln{a} + \ln{b}$ that use the integral definition of $\ln{x}$ but is there a proof that uses the limit definition $$\ln{x} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^h-1}{h}$$
I tried using squeeze theorem with AM-GM inequality on $a^h$ and $b^h$ $$a^h + b^h \ge 2\left( ab\right)^{h/2}$$ Which I could reduce to a lower bound
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} + \frac{b^h-1}{h} \ge \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2\left( \left( ab\right) ^{h/2}-1\right)}{\frac{h}{2}2}$$
$$\ln{a} + \ln{b} \ge \ln{ab}$$ But I couldn't complete the proof with an upper bound. I tried using the HM inequality $$\frac{4a^hb^h}{a^h + b^h} \ge a^h + b^h$$ $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{4a^hb^h}{a^h + b^h} - 2}{h} \ge \ln{a} + \ln{b}$$ But the left hand side just ended up giving me a useless upper bound $$\lim_{h\to 0} \left( \frac{2}{a^h+b^h}\right)\left( \frac{2\left( ab\right)^h-a^h-b^h}{h}\right)$$ $$\lim_{h\to 0}a^h\frac{b^h-1}{h} + b^h\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$ $$\ln{b} + \ln{a}$$
Is there a way to complete the squeeze theorem or even a different approach entirely to prove it

Comment: What is $x^h$ for real $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that

$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{a^h-1}{h}+\frac{b^h-1}{h}-\frac{(ab)^h-1}{h}\right)=\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{a^h+b^h-(ab)^h-1}{h}\right)=0
$$

We see $a^h+b^h-(ab)^h = b^h-a^h(b^h-1)$. As a result,

$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{a^h+b^h-(ab)^h-1}{h}\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}  \left(\frac{b^h-1}{h} -\frac{a^h(b^h-1)}{h} \right)=\ln{b}-\ln{b}=0.
$$

Comment: Essentially the same as my answer, except for two mistakes of sign: $a^h+b^h-(ab)^h =- a^h(b^h-1)+b^h,$ and $\frac{a^h+b^h-(ab)^h-1}{h}=-\frac{a^h(b^h-1)}{h} +\frac{b^h-1}{h}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Indeed they are essentially the same. One uses the trick of creating terms and another one uses the trick of combining terms. Both are useful in the study of calculus. But the more important point is commuting product sign and limit sign.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}\ln(ab)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(ab)^h-1}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(a^h-1)b^h+(b^h-1)}h\\&=(\ln a)b^0+\ln b.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) := a^x$ and $g(x) := b^x$.  Then by definition, we have $f'(0) = \ln a$ and $g'(0) = \ln b$.  On the other hand, since $f(x) g(x) = (ab)^x$, we also have $(fg)'(0) = \ln(ab)$.  Therefore, the product formula for derivatives gives
$$\ln(ab) = (fg)'(0) = f(0) g'(0) + g(0) f'(0) = 1 \cdot \ln b + 1 \cdot \ln a.$$

(If you unfold the usual proof of the product formula for derivatives, what you end up with is essentially the answer by Anne Bauval.)